# Gradle task is not mapping wsdl:portType from the WSDL to the service endpoint interface

Tags: java, spring, build.gradle, soap-client, gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a SOAP client in my spring application. I haven't ever worked on SOAP clients before. I looked it up and found a basic [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) on it and I am following this tutorial to add a SOAP client to my Spring application.

The first step is to map the WSDL file to the Java classes. For that I wrote a gradle script as described in the tutorial. When I run the above script, it generates classes from `xs:complexType` and `xs:element` but it doesn't generate any service endpoint interface from `wsdl:portType`

Gradle task:

```
task genJaxb {
ext.sourcesDir = "${projectDir}/java/main"
ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/main"
ext.schema = "java/main/resources/wsdl_file.wsdl"

outputs.dir classesDir

doLast() {
    project.ant {
        taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
        mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
        mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                    package: "com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl") {
                    arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                        src(path: sourcesDir)
                        include(name: "**/*.java")
                        include(name: "*.java")
                    }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                    fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Only dependencies that I am using for this:

```
dependencies{
    .
    .
    .
    jaxb 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11'
    jaxb 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jxc-core:2.2.11'
    jaxb 'org.glassfish.jaxb:xjc-core:2.2.11'
}
```

Any reason why it isn't generating the service endpoint interface using `wsdl:portType`?

Comment: Because you only build for JAXB which is generating classes from schema's it is not for generating webservice stubs.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what shall I use instead of JAXB to generate webservice stubs?

Comment: The Apache CXF plugin is what comes to mind.

Comment: yes, (cxf) "wsdl2java"/ (jaxws) "wsimport"...